# Refresh DocuSign access token in Appian connected system

Tags: docusignapi, appian

I have created an appian **Connected System** for DocuSign authentication with **Authenticate Code Grant**. I am able to authenticate & hit APIs successfully. But the issue is my token gets expired every 8 hours, then I have to go and authenticate from **Connected System** file again.
Please help me understand how can I refresh my token when its expired/about to expire.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain how refresh tokens are used to generate a new access token.
However, this may not be possible with Appian, I am not sure about that, because I'm not sure about how Appian works.

First, you have to store the **refresh_token** you got when you used Auth Code Grant to get the original **access_token** that expired. That token can used to get another **access_token** later.

To get a new access token, use the **refresh_token** as you would an authorization code, but with a **grant_type** value of **refresh_token** and a **refresh_token** parameter that holds the contents of the **refresh_token**.

[Read more in this Developer Center page](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20a%20new%20access,contents%20of%20the%20refresh%20token.&text=grant_type-,The%20type%20of%20grant%20being%20used.,an%20access%20token%2C%20use%20refresh_token%20.)